# MySQL Left Join Subselect

Tags: mysql, left-join, subquery

I have a simple table of languages / template id's:

language | template

en, t1
en, t1
au, t2
ge, t3
en, t1
ge, t2
ge, t3

Template is always either t1,t2, or t3. In total there are 3 languages: en, au, ge.

There is lots more information in the table, I am just showing what is relevant to this question, I will be using the data for graphing and so need it returning in this format:

en, t1, 3
en, t2, 0
en, t3, 0
au, t1, 0
au, t2, 1
au, t3, 0
ge, t1, 0
ge, t2, 1
ge, t3, 2

This counts however many template occurrences there are in each language. But, the problem I have is returning a zero count if there are no template id's for that particular language in the table.

I was thinking it would need some sort of left join sub select on the template id to make sure the 3 template id's are returned for each language?

Comment: why don't you write the SQL, so we can see where (or if) there are errors?

Comment: Is there also a templates table and/or a languages table? Or is this one table the only source of this data?

Comment: select a.template, count(a.template) as count, a.language, from table a
left join (select distinct(template) from table) b
on a.template = b.template
group by a.template, a.language order by a.language, a.template

Comment: @JoshuaCarmody This is the only table, which is why I think I would need to "left join (select distinct(template).." on the same table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There might be a better way of doing this, and I haven't tested it in MySQL, but the following works in SQL Server 2005:

```
Select a.language, b.template, count (c.template) as combo_count
from
(select distinct language from tablename) as a
inner join (select distinct template from tablename) as b on 1 < 2 /* this could be cross join, same thing. */
left outer join tablename c on c.language = a.language and c.template = b.template
group by a.language, b.template
order by 1, 2
```

Here are the results with your sample data:

```
au  t1  0
au  t2  1
au  t3  0
en  t1  3
en  t2  0
en  t3  0
ge  t1  0
ge  t2  1
ge  t3  2
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was after and works fine in MySQL. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select a.language, a.template, Count(*) count
  From (Select Distinct language, template From table) a
     Left Join table b
         On b.language = a.language
             And b.template = b.template
  Group By a.language, a.template
```

Comment: I've given this a try although am still getting the same as I would using the query in my above comment (no zero values). Also, why group first on language shouldn't it be a.template, a.language?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is two tables that list the possible values for language and template.

```
CREATE TABLE language (...) AS SELECT DISTINCT language FROM your_table;
CREATE TABLE template (...) AS SELECT DISTINCT template FROM your_table;
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT l.language, t.template, SUM(CASE WHEN yours.language IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) count
FROM language l CROSS JOIN template t
LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table yours ON l.language = yours.language AND t.template = yours.template
GROUP BY l.language, t.template;
```

Comment: Using two tables would be the same as doing: "FROM (select distinct(language) from table) l CROSS JOIN (select distinct(template) from table) t" in your above code wouldn't it? I've given this a go although I get the same results as in the below answer.