# How to join 2 queries to sort users by location in sql

Tags: mysql

I have a complex query returning a list of users with their details, and would like to sort them by distance according to a particular user latitude and longitude. So far I manage to pull their information on one side, and sort users using the haversine formula on the other, but after trying for many hours I still haven't managed yet to mix both queries into a single one.

Would anyone know how to do that?

Here are my 2 queries:

```
/* list of users with their information */
SELECT x.* 
  FROM ow_base_user x
  JOIN ow_base_user y
    ON y.id = x.id  
  LEFT 
  JOIN ow_base_user_suspend z
    ON z.userId = y.id 
 WHERE z.id IS NULL
   AND y.emailVerify = 1
 ORDER 
    BY x.joinStamp DESC LIMIT 100 

/* sort users by distance according to user 1 lat and lng */
SELECT l.id
     , l.lat
     , l.lng
     , haversine(l.lat,l.lng,u.lat,u.lng)*111.045 distance 
  FROM ow_googlelocation_data u
     , ow_googlelocation_data l 
 WHERE l.entityType = 'user' 
   AND u.id = 1 
 ORDER 
    BY distance
```

EDIT:

Here is the output of the first query:
[image: list of users with detail]

And of the second query:
[image: users sorted by distance]

I would like to have as an output the first query + distance field of the second query, and everything sorted by distance.

EDIT 2: Here is a [dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxxAR9Yb-g8BRzFQc2VjZk1GdTA/view?usp=sharing) of the tables with dummy content and the original queries if you want to try it out

Comment: Can you provide sample output from both queries (top 5 rows or something) and how you would expect the output to look?

Comment: The second screenshot does not work!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? I see it displayed...

Comment: ok sorry, now it is there. Before it showed a broken link.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but is the id in the second query also the user id?

Comment: You can use a sub select in a join: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520441/mysql-left-join-subselect

Comment: SELECT u.* FROM ow_base_user as u 
...

INNER JOIN (

SELECT l.id, l.lat, l.lng, haversine(l.lat,l.lng,u.lat,u.lng)*111.045 as distance 
FROM ow_googlelocation_data u, ow_googlelocation_data l 
WHERE l.entityType='user' and u.id = 1 ) as d
on d.id = u.id

order by d.distance

I don't want to write an answer since I can't test it...Please try it

Comment: Did you intend to include the distance from the user to herself (i.e. 0) in the result? And your formula only works on the equator!! Beyond that, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. Obviously, use dummy data, if the real data is sensitive.

Comment: @Strawberry: no I don't if possible

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid: yes it's the same user id, for your query some of the join of the first query are missing, aren't they?

Comment: That's were I inserted '...' the query was too long for a comment. Just add the inner join after your first query.

Comment: Hum it's still doesn't work, so I edited my post with a link to an archive with an example in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i've been changing the table alias into something a bit more readable, let me know.

```
SELECT 
    u1.*, 
    loc1.lat, 
    loc1.lng, 
    haversine(loc1.lat,loc1.lng,loc2.lat,loc2.lng)*111.045 as distance
FROM 
    ow_googlelocation_data as loc2,
    ow_base_user as u1 INNER JOIN ow_base_user u2
        ON u1.id = u2.id
    LEFT JOIN ow_base_user_suspend s
        ON s.userId = u1.id
    INNER JOIN ow_googlelocation_data as loc1 
        ON loc1.entityId = u1.id
WHERE
    s.id IS NULL AND
    u1.emailVerify = 1 AND
    loc1.entityType='user' AND
    loc2.entityType = 'user' AND
    u1.id != loc2.entityId AND
    loc2.entityId = 1
ORDER BY 
    distance ASC
LIMIT 100
```